# Receiving http response in multiple activities in Android

Tags: android, rest, http

I have three activities that show data that is obtained as response to http request.

In the fourth activity, if I do a transaction, data of previous three activities become outdated. The new response will contain the updated data that should be reflected in these three activities.

What is the best method to achieve this ? Should the request be done on service and then local broadcast should be used or is there some way to notify the three activities of new updated data from fourth activity ?

Comment: You could parse your latest data through intent.putExtra(Bundle) when you start an activity. You could create an interface and listen to updates or you could indeed use broadcast receiver. You could even store your data to an sqlite database and update/select as required. Not really an answer but just a few ideas to show some options

Answer (score 0):

I would do the request on an intent service and register broadcastrecievers in the Activities. I would also store a flag/ or the data in shared preferences/sql and have the Activity check this in onCreate(); This because if your activity is destroyed it will not recieve the broadcast.